# Postgres: How to convert SQL result into column name & value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one table which contains the data and all column are in text type.

Sample data as shown below

```
SELECT name, setting 
FROM pg.settings 
WHERE name IN ('log_destination', 'logging_collector', 'log_directory', 'log_filename', 'log_line_prefix')
```

[image]

Now I want to convert these two columns into individual `column name` -> `value` format.

Expected output:

| log_directory | log_filename | log_line_prefix | logging_collector | log_destination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| log | postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log | %t | off | csvlog,syslog |

How can I archive this using plain SQL?
Please suggest.

Comment: I think You can use the crosstab function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation, which in Postgres uses `filter`:

```
SELECT MAX(setting) FILTER (WHERE name = 'log_destination') as log_destination,
       MAX(setting) FILTER (WHERE name = 'logging_collector') as logging_collector,
       MAX(setting) FILTER (WHERE name = 'log_directory') as log_directory,
       MAX(setting) FILTER (WHERE name = 'log_filename') as log_filename,
       MAX(setting) FILTER (WHERE name = 'log_line_prefix') as log_line_prefix,
FROM pg.settings s
WHERE name IN ('log_destination', 'logging_collector', 'log_directory', 'log_filename', 'log_line_prefix');
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you @Gordon Linoff